# Real time video rendering in skybox

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**I want to play 360 video at skybox**. Is there any direct way avaiable to do this task. One long boring procedure which seems that

1. convert 360 to frames
2. convert frames into cubmap
3. use that cube map in skybox and programatically change it quickly so that video effects shown

This is the long task which seems to me possible but is there any other way available.

**Update after Answer:**

Thanks to Umair M answer i am able to run video inside sphere but getting black circle why?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A better way to play 360 video is using [MovieTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html). Use `movieTexture` on a sphere and place the camera right at centre of sphere. Make sure that the shader you apply to sphere object has `cull = off` property to render from inside.

Read this for more: [Full 360 stereoscopic video playback in Unity](http://bernieroehl.com/360stereoinunity/)

N.B : If you don't want to do all of it by yourself, there are few good assets on store that you can use: 
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/35102
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/2546

Comment: Thanks Umair it perfectly hepled. I dont know about shader programming and its so powerful who do the job. I am getting black ciricle inside spehere please tell me about it and why this is not correclty working in cube primitive?

Comment: did you follow the tutorial post?

Comment: use [this shader](https://github.com/Unitarian/Unity-Extensions/blob/master/InsideSphere.shader) on your material.

Comment: i applied that shader but still it is showing black circle inside

Comment: Can you tell me what steps did you do?

Comment: 1. added a 360 video in ogv format, 2. make a standaar shader and just added cull off in it 2. make a cube 4. apply that shader 5. add moveTexture play script to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122666/discussion-between-umair-m-and-mohammad-faizan-khan).